# Drawing a bar chart and color it

Tags: python, python-turtle

You decide to keep track of the number of pizzas sold for each type every day with a
stacked bar chart. Use the turtle module to draw the bar chart with the following
requirements:

- Each bar includes four rectangles representing the number of pizzas sold for each
  type. From bottom to top, they are large thick, large thin, medium thick and medium
  thin respectively.
- Each rectangle is of a different color.
- Draw the x and y axes.
- The record date must be printed below the bar.
- The total number of pizzas must be printed on top of the bar.

```
def draw_bar_chart(record_date, large_thick, large_thin, medium_thick, medium_thin): 
    # your logic here 
    # you don’t need to return anything
```

Ive been stuck on this question for 2 days. I figured out the drawing parts, but the filling colors and others is a bit much for me. Can someone help me ?

Image:

[image]

Comment: first example in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) shows how to use `begin_fill()` and `end_fill()`. You have to only draw closed figure (like rectangle) to get color inside

Comment: you have [turtle.write()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.write) to display text. It can be useful also `turtle.hideturtle()`, `turtle.showturtle()` to move in new place without drawing line.

Comment: This is missing a [mcve] and [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) is probably relevant.